# How to return zero for a field in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am generating crystal report from database. My requirement is to when the field TKK Balance returns 0 or more than 0 for a row the report will print a dash '-' for that row and if it is less than 0 then only it will return the original value from the database. Is there anyone who can help  me on this? please?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all it can be done inside the SQL select statement like this

```
,(
    CASE WHEN [TKKBalance] >= 0
        THEN '-'
        ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [TKKBalance])
    END
) AS [SomeName]
```

or, you can create and use a formula field inside your report with the following code

```
if {TableName.TKKBalance} >= 0 then
    "-"
else
    totext({TableName.TKKBalance})
```